# Product of divisible module is divisible

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, examples-counterexamples

I have the following problem

> Is the product of divisible $R$-modules divisible?

I think it is not. But I need some counterexample to this, somebody can give me a "place" to search one?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The most obvious approach to this proves the result...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Considering the product of $\mathbb{Q}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-module?

Comment: @YotasTrejos : Why do you believe the statement isn't true? If you really have a reason, then that should generate a counterexample. If you don't have a reason, you should attempt a positive proof.

Comment: The result is true... Thanks for the advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suposse that $\{M_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda} $ is family of divisible $R$-modules and consider $Z=\prod_{\lambda\in\Lambda} M_\lambda$. Take $r\in R$ and $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\in Z$, we can chose for each $\lambda$ an element $y_\lambda$ such that $r y_{\lambda}=x_\lambda$ then we have that $r (y_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}=(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$. With this we prove that $Z$ is divisible.